# Phone awake while running the application

Tags: android

I implement a application and it works properly.Now I want to know how prevent that going to sleeping mobile phone,while particular application running.I tried to implement using **awake lock** now I want to implement after given time run screen saver and again touch screen running current application properly.Because use **awake lock** phone awake till app run.But user away for few time I want to run Screensaver until start again

Comment: It isn't understood what you want. Using `WakeLock` you can make device stay awake while running the app.

Comment: Do you want to keep the app running or do you want to prevent the screen to go off?

Comment: keep the app running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Keep the Screen On**

The best way to do this is to use the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON in your activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }
```

Another way to implement this is in your application's layout XML file, by using the android:keepScreenOn attribute:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Keep the CPU On**

If you need to keep the CPU running in order to complete some work before the device goes to sleep, you can use a PowerManager system service feature called wake locks. Wake locks allow your application to control the power state of the host device.

Creating and holding wake locks can have a dramatic impact on the host device's battery life. Thus you should use wake locks only when strictly necessary and hold them for as short a time as possible. For example, you should never need to use a wake lock in an activity. As described above, if you want to keep the screen on in your activity, use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON.

One legitimate case for using a wake lock might be a background service that needs to grab a wake lock to keep the CPU running to do work while the screen is off. Again, though, this practice should be minimized because of its impact on battery life.

To use a wake lock, the first step is to add the WAKE_LOCK permission to your application's manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

If your app includes a broadcast receiver that uses a service to do some work, you can manage your wake lock through a WakefulBroadcastReceiver, as described in Using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver. This is the preferred approach. If your app doesn't follow that pattern, here is how you set a wake lock directly:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

To release the wake lock, call `wakelock.release().` This releases your claim to the CPU. It's important to release a wake lock as soon as your app is finished using it to avoid draining the battery.

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

And add this in your onCreate :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);    
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```